# Add a last modified date column for each row in Sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: 2010, list, list-definition, date-time

I have a list where I have some columns, my requirement is that I need to add a column, which will update the **last modified date for each row**.

That is if I edit one row today, **add today's date to the last modified column to only the edited row**. The other rows values should be unchanged, unless that rows modified!!

Is there any, Out of box functionality to do this, or should I go for some custom code?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should show last modified date of row in list view, am I right? In this case you could select List tab in the ribbon, click on modify view button, in the fields list select check box near the Modified field, click ok. This field will be added to the view.

Comment: To update your answer, in Microsoft 365 this feature can be accessed with:            
"All Items" dropdown in the ribbon -> Edit current view -> Select "Modified" check box